# Circles "waves" animations with CSS keyframes

Tags: html, css, sass, keyframe

I'm trying to animate circles to achieve an infinite effect of colliding waves.

I laid the base but I can't make the order of the animations smooth and linear.

[Codepen available here](https://codepen.io/lorraineS/pen/GRxpJPd).

```
<div class="circles-container"
    <!-- 1er circle -->
    <svg width="1280" height="1280" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="z-index: 1;">
      <path class="circle-1" d="M0 0h640c0 353.466-286.534 640-640 640V0Z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
    <!-- 2eme circle -->
    <svg width="1280" height="1280" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="z-index: 2;">
      <path class="circle-2" d="M0 0h640c0 353.466-286.534 640-640 640V0Z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
    <!-- 3eme circle -->
    <svg width="1280" height="1280" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="z-index: 3;">
      <path class="circle-3" d="M0 0h640c0 353.466-286.534 640-640 640V0Z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
</div>


.circles-container { position: relative; }

.circles-container svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.circle-1 {
  animation: scaleCircle 7.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  color: #1D1D28;
}

.circle-2 {
  animation: scaleCircle 5s ease-in-out infinite 2.5s;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  color: #420DC4;
}

.circle-3 {
  animation: scaleCircle 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  color: #1D1D28;
}

@keyframes scaleCircle {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

Here is the scenario:

When loading, a first blue circle is displayed.

1. A first black circle grows until it crushes the blue circle
2. at 50% of step's 1 animation, a new blue circle is displayed and enlarged until it overwrites the black circle created during step 1
3. back to step 1

In my render, you can see that the circles are showing but some are hiding too soon, etc. The circles should display one after the other in a linear fashion.

Is it possible to do this in full CSS with keyframes ?

Comment: Please provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read [why an image of your code is not acceptable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) which applies also to any other external resource such as a Codepen. It explains why a Codepen is not an acceptable substitute to provide debugging informations.

Comment: Ok sorry, I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are going for but maybe you can tinker with it.

So with  4 circles you can animate the scale basically the way you have it. And then for their svg container, you animate the z-index so whenever a wave starts it gets its highest z-index and then it deceases before the next wave starts.

```
<div class="circles-container">
  
  <!-- 1er cercle -->
  <svg class="circle-parent-1" width="1280" height="1280" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path class="circle-1" d="M0 0h640c0 353.466-286.534 640-640 640V0Z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" />
  </svg>

  <!-- 2eme cercle -->
  <svg  class="circle-parent-2" width="1280" height="1280" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    <path class="circle-2" d="M0 0h640c0 353.466-286.534 640-640 640V0Z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" />
  </svg>
  
  <svg  class="circle-parent-3" width="1280" height="1280" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    <path class="circle-3" d="M0 0h640c0 353.466-286.534 640-640 640V0Z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" />
  </svg>
  

  <svg  class="circle-parent-4" width="1280" height="1280" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    <path class="circle-4" d="M0 0h640c0 353.466-286.534 640-640 640V0Z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" />
  </svg>
  
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.circles-container { position: relative; }

.circles-container svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.circle-parent-1 {
  animation: zIndexCircle 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circle-parent-2 {
  animation: zIndexCircle 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.circle-parent-3 {
  animation: zIndexCircle 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circle-parent-3 {
  animation: zIndexCircle 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.circle-parent-4 {
  animation: zIndexCircle 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}


.circle-1 {
  animation: scaleCircle 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-delay:0s;
  transform: scale(0);
  color: #1D1D28;
}

.circle-2 {
  animation: scaleCircle 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-delay:2s;
  transform: scale(0);
  color: #420DC4;
}

.circle-3 {
  animation: scaleCircle 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-delay:4s;
  transform: scale(0);
  color: #1D1D28;
}

.circle-4 {
  animation: scaleCircle 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-delay:6s;
  transform: scale(0);
  color: #420DC4;
}

@keyframes zIndexCircle {
    0% {
    z-index:5;
  }
  25% {
    z-index: 4;
  }
  50% {
    z-index:3;
  }
  75% {
    z-index:2;
  }
  
  100% {
    z-index:1;
  }
}
@keyframes scaleCircle {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  75% {
     transform: scale(2);
  } 
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/todilo-the-vuer/pen/XWEmdXL

Comment: Yes, that's almost it!
The only problem I see (which is also present in my base code) is that the final circle is removed before the incoming circle can completely cover it.

For example in the 1st iteration, the black circle is removed before the blue completely covers it.

Comment: @Fyl fixed that. Changed the scale animation to be done at 75% and then just linger at scale(2) until 100%